# What is the typical sentence for BURGLARY - OCCUPIED DWELLING UNARMED?

Tags: united-states, florida, sentencing

Just asking for a friend in South Florida.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good question for two reasons:

1. Criminal sentencing guidelines vary by jurisdiction and can be readily found by searching for `sentencing guidelines` and the jurisdiction in question.
2. Sentencing "typically" depends on factors beyond the crime committed.  These [commonly include](http://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-procedure/factors-considered-in-determining-sentences.html):

   - whether the offender is a "first-time" or repeat offender
   - whether the offender was an accessory (helping the main offender) or the main offender
   - whether the offender committed the crime under great personal stress or duress
   - whether anyone was hurt, and whether the crime was committed in a manner that was unlikely to result in anyone being hurt
   - whether the offender was particularly cruel to a victim, or particularly destructive, etc.
   - whether the offender is genuinely contrite or remorseful

Comment: 3) the friend is potentially facing a serious criminal charge, and should be consulting with actual lawyers rather than random people online

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Florida Statutes, section 810.02](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0800-0899/0810/Sections/0810.02.html), this is probably a felony in the second degree, although there are circumstances you have not covered (using a vehicle to make entry, or causing sufficient damage, or assaulting an occupant of the structure, or during a state of emergency) that could make it a felony in the first degree.  The relevant sentence is covered by either section 775.082 or section 775.084.

According to [section 775.082](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0700-0799/0775/Sections/0775.082.html), a felony in the first degree carries a sentence of up to 30 years in prison unless otherwise provided by statute; section 810.02 provides otherwise and first-degree burglary carries a sentence of up to life imprisonment.  A felony in the second degree carries a sentence of up to 15 years in prison.

If this is the third felony the offender is convicted of, [section 75.084 (habitual felony offenders)](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0700-0799/0775/Sections/0775.084.html) applies and the potential sentence is life imprisonment for first-degree felony burglary, or up to 30 years for second-degree.

Comment: Good references, but not necessarily responsive to the OP: there can be quite a disconnect between _typical_ sentences and the _maximum allowed_ sentence.